# React Native: Detect captured image is not blurred

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image

I got a requirement that I have to make sure the captured image is not blurred before uploading it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the image content as binary you can run it past various JavaScript libraries to do blur detection.

Search: "Detect image is blurry in JavaScript" to see options.

## Example Option

Using opencv.js : https://github.com/rahullahoria/js-blur-image-detection

```
        let src = cv.imread(imgElement);
        let dst = new cv.Mat();
        let men = new cv.Mat();
        let menO = new cv.Mat();
        cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);
        // You can try more different parameters
        var t = cv.Laplacian(src, dst, cv.CV_64F, 1, 1, 0, cv.BORDER_DEFAULT);
        console.log(t,cv.meanStdDev(dst, menO, men),menO.data64F[0], men.data64F[0]);
        if(men.data64F[0] > 10)
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Not blur";
        else
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "blur";
```

Comment: But unable to install or use opencv.js in react native.